# 19 characters to one prediction

Tags: neural-networks

I want to read the KELM natural sentences 19 characters at a time and predict the 20th character. So i made AN enumerator that returns that moving window of characters and already encode each of the characters to 5 bit Number. I take all of them, make uppercase, and keep ",.:;" space and newline. That makes 31 characters,others are discarded, enough to be encoded in 5 bits. Foreach bit of each character I map It to 1.0f of bit Is set, otherwise to -1.0f. so my input Vector Is 19*5=95 floating point values. And of course the output Is Just 5 floating point values.

Thus i provide a starting sentences of 19 characters, and I expect a good prediction on next character. Then I can discard the First character of sentences, append the predicted character and make the NN predict the next One and so on.

Now I partially succeed. In the sense i comeup with 2 Networks configurations that somehow generate sequence of words separated by comma or by space with some 4/5 random characters. (Green lines on excel)

[image: l]

But increasing any hyperparameter makes It worse (loses the separatore character or go back to 2/3 characters at most). The last line of excell returns only AAAAs..

I'm using Keras.Net with C#